# What are “auj.”, “ev.”, “ar.” used as address or location abbreviations?

Tags: abréviations, canada

I see these abbreviations a lot and still cannot find the answer for these words set in location descriptions:

- auj.
- ev.
- ar.

> St-Etienne De Mortagne (Auj. Mortagne-Sur-Gironde), Ev. Saintes, Saintonge (Ar. Saintes, Charente-Maritime)
>
> st-pierre, frontenay-l'abbatu, ev. saintes, saintonge (auj. frontenay-rohan-rohan, ar. niort, deux-sevres)
>
> "Notre-Dame, Nachamps, ev. Saintes, Saintonge (ar. St-Jean-d’Angely, Charente-Maritime)"

I have the paragraph here, but for months, I have been trying to figure out addresses and locations written in French, Quebec French

[image]

Living in Lachine, jean Mouflet, his wife Anne Dodain and two of their children Marguerite and Angélique Gabrielle seemed to have vanished on the day after the 5th of August 1689 (source: MSGCF 50 (3) . we surmise that they were killed or captured during the Lachine Massacre.

Answer (score 2):

*Auj.* is short for "*Aujourd'hui*". It means the town changed its name since he was born.

> Birth : Circa 1645 in St-Etienne De Mortagne, now Mortagne-Sur-Gironde

*Ar.* is short for "*Arrondissement*", [Saintes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrondissement_of_Saintes) is an *arrondissement* of the Charentes-Maritimes department.

I'm not exactly sure what *ev.* means, but it's probably short for the region name before arrondissement were adopted in [1800](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrondissements_of_France#History).

So the current location is:

> [Mortagne-Sur-Gironde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortagne-sur-Gironde), Arrondissement Saintes, Charente-Maritime

However it's not a full adress, it's just the city. It's kind of like saying "Houston, Texas", the last part indicating the region, except it's not very useful because in France there are (almost) no two cities with the same name where you'd need to add the region to be unambiguous.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I also got this. But the first answer helps the most, for sure. auj. Aujourd'hui (today or nowadays depending on the sentence)

Comment: ev. Évêché refers to the administrative level in catholic system, Évêché will take care of many parishes

Comment: ar. Arrondissement : means borough

Comment: When they say, "Charente-Maritime" it refers to it as "the department." Even in Wiki is says the department of.. When I think of a department, I think of people, government, a business department. I think they are referring to a small region. Is this a physical region like a township? 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charente-Maritime

Comment: Are they then actually referring to "Charente-Inférieure" which was renamed Charente-Maritime?

Comment: @Vogued "Département" is a territorial subdivision, like the US have state and counties, [France](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_administrative_divisions_by_country) has Régions, Départements, Arrondissements, and Cantons. It's not really the same meaning as "department" in English.